# ES6 .filter within a .filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So I have data like the following:

```
[
     {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "happy dayys",
      "owner": {"id": "1", "username": "dillonraphael"},
      "tags": [{"value": "Art", "label": "Art"}],
      "items": []
     },
     {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "happy dayys",
      "owner": {"id": "1", "username": "dillonraphael"},
      "tags": [{"value": "Architecture", "label": "Architecture"}],
      "items": []
     },
]
```

I'm trying to filter through an array and only return if the tags array contains a value that is `==` to another string.

This is what I came up with but still seems to be sending back the whole array:

```
const tagMoodboards = _moodboards.filter(mb => { return mb.tags.filter(t => t.value == name) })
```

Comment: You need to use `map()` to return clones with filtered arrays.

Comment: What is the desired result and what's in `mb.tags`?  I don't follow what the objective is.

Comment: If i understand the question right, the inner part looks more like an application for [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: `mb.tags.filter(t => t.value == name)` will _always_ be an array, so it’s always truthy, so the outer `filter` is equivalent to just `const tagMoodboards = _moodboards.filter(mb => { return true })`.

Comment: Although filter() not best approach on the inner .... return the length of the resultant array  instead of the array itself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want a `filter` inside a `filter` - rather, inside the filter, check if `some` of the `tags` objects have the `.value` property that you want

```js
const _moodboards = [
     {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "happy dayys",
      "owner": {"id": "1", "username": "dillonraphael"},
      "tags": [{"value": "Art", "label": "Art"}],
      "items": []
     },
     {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "happy dayys",
      "owner": {"id": "1", "username": "dillonraphael"},
      "tags": [{"value": "Architecture", "label": "Architecture"}],
      "items": []
     },
];
const name = 'Architecture';
console.log(_moodboards.filter(({ tags }) => (
  tags.some(({ value }) => value === name)
)));
```

Answer (score 2):

To use `filter()` you need something that will return true or false -- i.e. a Boolean. That should be the first place you start. So given an object like

```
{
 "id": 0,
 "title": "happy dayys",
 "owner": {"id": "1", "username": "dillonraphael"},
 "tags": [{"value": "Art", "label": "Art"}],
 "items": []
},
```

if you want to decide whether or not that should be used, you might try [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on the `tags` array. This will return a boolean.

```js
let tags = [{"value": "Art", "label": "Art"}]

console.log(tags.some(tag => tag.value = "Art")) // true
```

With that in hand, you can now use `filter()` and `some()` together. `some()` will return true or false for each item in the array and that will determine whether it's filtered or not:

```js
let arr =  [{"id": 0,"title": "happy dayys","owner": {"id": "1", "username": "dillonraphael"},"tags": [{"value": "Art", "label": "Art"}],"items": []},{"id": 1,"title": "happy dayys","owner": {"id": "1", "username": "dillonraphael"},"tags": [{"value": "Architecture", "label": "Architecture"}],"items": []},]

console.log(arr.filter(obj => obj.tags.some(o => o.value == 'Art') ))
```