# How to filter nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my json data -

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "deviceId": "2a-d539-4031-9bfc-4a42f2f765cf",
      "versions": [
        {
          "id": "764c20-a213-9235f4b553b3",
          "createdTime": 1590361208034,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN"
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "OUT_OF_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED"
        },
        {
          "id": "9bd33-a45a-ed2fefc46931",
          "createdTime": 1589972337717,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "RUNNINGCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "IN_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED_FIRST_TIME"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter data, where "fileType": "RUNNINGCONFIG", and "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG", is present inside 'files' only return that array.

e.g. From the above json only second object will be returned.

I tried to write some Filter code but it is not working properly, guide me.

```
let versionsData = response.data.versions;


versionsData = versionsData.filter(
                        versions => {
                            versions.files.filter(
                                m =>  {
                                    return m.fileType === "RUNNINGCONFIG"
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    );
                return versionsData;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of nested filter you could use `Array.prototype.some`

```js
const obj = {
  "list": [
    {
      "deviceId": "2a-d539-4031-9bfc-4a42f2f765cf",
      "versions": [
        {
          "id": "764c20-a213-9235f4b553b3",
          "createdTime": 1590361208034,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN"
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "OUT_OF_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED"
        },
        {
          "id": "9bd33-a45a-ed2fefc46931",
          "createdTime": 1589972337717,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "RUNNINGCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "IN_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED_FIRST_TIME"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
let versionsData = obj.list[0].versions;


versionsData = versionsData.filter(
    versions => 
        versions.files.some(
            m =>  m.fileType === "RUNNINGCONFIG"
        ) && versions.files.some(
            m => m.fileType== 'STARTUPCONFIG'
        )

);
console.log(versionsData);
```

With Array.prototype.filter

```js
const obj = {
  "list": [
    {
      "deviceId": "2a-d539-4031-9bfc-4a42f2f765cf",
      "versions": [
        {
          "id": "764c20-a213-9235f4b553b3",
          "createdTime": 1590361208034,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN"
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "OUT_OF_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED"
        },
        {
          "id": "9bd33-a45a-ed2fefc46931",
          "createdTime": 1589972337717,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "RUNNINGCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "IN_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED_FIRST_TIME"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
let versionsData = obj.list[0].versions;


versionsData = versionsData.filter( versions => {        return versions.files.filter( m => { 
     return m.fileType === "RUNNINGCONFIG" || m.fileType === "STARTUPCONFIG" }).length > 1 }
);
console.log(versionsData);
```

Comment: after running your code it still show 2 objects, it should be one right.

Comment: Do you need both conditions satisfied?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, yes both condition should be satisfied, I replaced || with && but it's not working.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri , Thanks its working. why instead of nested filter we are using some,

Comment: `Some` returns you true if a condition is satisfied by atleast one element in the array. However filter will loop on the entire array and returns you elements that satisfy the condition. It could have worked with filter too but you would need to change its implementation a bit

Comment: With filter you would need to write `versionsData.filter(
                        versions => {
                            versions.files.filter(
                                m =>  {
                                    return m.fileType === "RUNNINGCONFIG" || m.fileType === "STARTUPCONFIG"
                                }
                            ).length > 0
                        }
                    );`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri `versionsData.filter( versions => { versions.files.filter( m => { return m.fileType === "RUNNINGCONFIG" || m.fileType === "STARTUPCONFIG" } ).length > 0 } )` seems not to be working.

Comment: @RahulDwivedi I updated my answer for it. The issue was in .length check. IT must be > 1 or `precisely .length === 2` which would mean both conditions satisfied. However it is not that reliable as files array can have duplicate entries of filetype

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri hmm that's interesting because what I was thinking was this:
 the inner `filter` would either return an array or `[]` (`truthy` or `false`), in which case, outer array should precisely become this: `versionsData.filter( versions => true`` which in turn would print the whole `versionData` or just an `[]` in case of `false`. Shouldn't it be like this?

Comment: Not really, the inner filter will return an array with 2 elements if both filetypes are present, 1 element if one filetype is present and 0 elements if none are present

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yeah so when inner filter returns an array with 2 elements, it becomes `truthy` and in the case it returning `[]`, it becomes falsy. So precisely it should become `arr.filter(i=> 'true' or 'false')`; check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128388/es6-filter-within-a-filter

Comment: an empty array is not a falsy value but a truthy one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214743/discussion-between-rahul-dwivedi-and-shubham-khatri).

Answer (score 1):

A way with filter inside of filter.

```js
let data = {
  "list": [
    {
      "deviceId": "2a-d539-4031-9bfc-4a42f2f765cf",
      "versions": [
        {
          "id": "764c20-a213-9235f4b553b3",
          "createdTime": 1590361208034,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN"
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "OUT_OF_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED"
        },
        {
          "id": "9bd33-a45a-ed2fefc46931",
          "createdTime": 1589972337717,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "RUNNINGCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "IN_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED_FIRST_TIME"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};


let versionsData = /*response.*/data.list[0].versions;

versionsData = versionsData.filter(versions => {
  return versions.files.filter(m => {
    return m.fileType == 'RUNNINGCONFIG' || m.fileType == 'STARTUPCONFIG';
  }).length == 2;
});

console.log(versionsData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  "list": [
    {
      "deviceId": "2a-d539-4031-9bfc-4a42f2f765cf",
      "versions": [
        {
          "id": "764c20-a213-9235f4b553b3",
          "createdTime": 1590361208034,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN"
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "OUT_OF_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED"
        },
        {
          "id": "9bd33-a45a-ed2fefc46931",
          "createdTime": 1589972337717,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "RUNNINGCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "IN_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED_FIRST_TIME"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const filterData = () => {
  return data.list[0].versions.reduce((output, version) => {
    const fileTypes = version.files.map(f => f.fileType);

    return fileTypes.includes('STARTUPCONFIG') && fileTypes.includes('RUNNINGCONFIG') ? 
    [...output, version] : output
  }, [])
}

console.log(filterData());
```

Comment: You forget to add console, so that we can run and check.

Comment: added the log. please try now.