# Filter within a filter is working in one case, while it doesn't in another

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So I happened to go through these two posts:

1. [ES6 .filter within a .filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128388/es6-filter-within-a-filter)

   `[
        {
         "id": 0,
         "title": "happy dayys",
         "owner": {"id": "1", "username": "dillonraphael"},
         "tags": [{"value": "Art", "label": "Art"}],
         "items": []
        },
        {
         "id": 1,
         "title": "happy dayys",
         "owner": {"id": "1", "username": "dillonraphael"},
         "tags": [{"value": "Architecture", "label": "Architecture"}],
         "items": []
        },
   ]`

In this OP tried to filter the data though a nested filter which didn't work:

```
const tagMoodboards = _moodboards.filter(mb => { return mb.tags.filter(t => t.value == name) });
```

The reason for this is the inner `filter` returns an array (truthy) so for the outer array it becomes like this `_moodboards.filter(mb => true)` hence it prints the entire array

Then there's a similar problem

2. [How to filter nested array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62041349/how-to-filter-nested-array-in-javascript)

where there's a data like this:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "deviceId": "2a-d539-4031-9bfc-4a42f2f765cf",
      "versions": [
        {
          "id": "764c20-a213-9235f4b553b3",
          "createdTime": 1590361208034,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN"
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "OUT_OF_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED"
        },
        {
          "id": "9bd33-a45a-ed2fefc46931",
          "createdTime": 1589972337717,
          "files": [
            {
              "fileType": "VLAN",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG",
            },
            {
              "fileType": "RUNNINGCONFIG",
            }
          ],
          "startupRunningStatus": "IN_SYNC",
          "createdBy": "SCHEDULED_FIRST_TIME"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and OP wanted to filter data, in a way that it should return only that array where "fileType": "RUNNINGCONFIG", and "fileType": "STARTUPCONFIG", is present

But in this case a `filter` within `filter` seems to do the job

`let versionsData = obj.list[0].versions;
    versionsData = versionsData.filter( versions => {        return versions.files.filter( m => { 
         return m.fileType === "RUNNINGCONFIG" || m.fileType === "STARTUPCONFIG" }).length > 1 }
    );
    console.log(versionsData);`

In the second case, I felt it should have followed the same pattern `versionData = versionData.filter(versions => true)` hence returning the complete array.

So, my question is what exactly am I missing here? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: don't put someone else's code inside your own. Just state your problem (with data), your attempt and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it to:

```
const tagMoodboards = _moodboards.filter(mb => { return mb.tags.filter(t => t.value == name).length });
```

For Rahul:
Paste this code in browser console:

```
let arr = [
    {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "happy dayys",
    "owner": {"id": "1", "username": "dillonraphael"},
    "tags": [{"value": "Art", "label": "Art"}],
    "items": []
    },
    {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "happy dayys",
    "owner": {"id": "1", "username": "dillonraphael"},
    "tags": [{"value": "Architecture", "label": "Architecture"}],
    "items": []
    },
];

console.info(arr.filter(mb => { return mb.tags.filter(t => t.value == 'Art') })); // -> 2 hits (=wrong)
console.info(arr.filter(mb => { return mb.tags.filter(t => t.value == 'Art').length })); // -> 1 hit (=right)
```

Comment: What exactly should this do?

Comment: If name is 'Art', you will get one hit.  If you don't have the '.length' you will get two hits (full array).

Comment: `.length` tells you the length of an array. So `mb.tags.filter(t => t.value == name).length` is a number. If it's 0, it's falsy and the entry gets filtered out. If it's not 0, it's truthy and the entry is included. The case that does work is similar, but with `> 0`, to explicitly convert to a boolean.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I think I'm getting it a bit now. One clarification, I require though, if I don't put the `length`, it will still return something as in `truthy` or `falsy`. As in both the cases, it becomes, myArray.filter(i=> `true` or `false`); so it should either return the whole array (depending upon on `truthy` condition or empty array on the basis of `false`). So how does `length` impacting the result now?

Comment: Without `.length` it's just the array itself. In javascript arrays are always truthy, even if they're empty. E.g. try `if ([]) { console.log('This empty array is truthy'); }`, or `console.log(!![]);`.

Comment: I checked this in chrome83:   console.info(arr.filter(mb => { return mb.tags.filter(t => t.value == 'Art') })); // -> 2 hits (=wrong)
console.info(arr.filter(mb => { return mb.tags.filter(t => t.value == 'Art').length })); // -> 1 hit (=right)